# Custom toolbar issues

Tags: codenameone

I have a written a custom toolbar. And I am having tough time to make it work (design wise). I have a couple of questions regarding it.

1)The main issue I am facing is to place the menu icons in their exact positions. When I tested it in different devices the gaps betn them is different.I have used table layout and grid layout for the menu icons as well & the logo in layered layout but the result is not good.

Code:

```
void addTitle(Form form, Resources theme) {
    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
    form.setToolbar(toolbar);

    Container containerTitle = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    Image titleImage = theme.getImage("toolbar_bg.jpg");
    containerTitle.getAllStyles().setBgImage(titleImage);
    containerTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_HORIZONTAL);
    containerTitle.setPreferredH(titleImage.getHeight());

    ScaleImageButton ruslanLogo = new ScaleImageButton();

    toolbar.setTitleComponent(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(containerTitle,
            FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ruslanLogo)));
    Image ruslanLogoImage = theme.getImage("ruslanLogo.png").scaledWidth(toolbar.getPreferredH() - 180);
    ruslanLogo.setIcon(ruslanLogoImage);

    Image emergencyImage = theme.getImage("emergency.png");
    Image receipeImage = theme.getImage("receipe.png");
    Image fmImage = theme.getImage("fm.png");
    Image gameImage = theme.getImage("game.png");

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(1, 5);
    //GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(5);
    Container tableContainer = new Container(tableLayout);

    Button emergencyButton = getButton(emergencyImage);
    emergencyButton.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);

    Button fmButton = getButton(fmImage);
    fmButton.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);

    Button gameButton = getButton(gameImage);
    gameButton.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);

    Button receipeButton = getButton(receipeImage);
    receipeButton.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);

    Button transparentButton = getButton(receipeImage);
    transparentButton.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
    transparentButton.setVisible(false);

    tableContainer.addComponent(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), BoxLayout.encloseY(emergencyButton));
    tableContainer.addComponent(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), BoxLayout.encloseY(fmButton));
    tableContainer.addComponent(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), BoxLayout.encloseY(transparentButton));
    tableContainer.addComponent(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), BoxLayout.encloseY(gameButton));
    tableContainer.addComponent(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), BoxLayout.encloseY(receipeButton));
    containerTitle.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, tableContainer);
    toolbar.revalidate();
}
```

2)I have checked the width and preferred width, they differs. Does it affects the design?

```
int width = emergencyButton.getWidth(); //60
int preferredwidth = emergencyButton.getPreferredW(); //74
```

3)In above code, I used the bg image height to set the height of the toolbar. "containerTitle.setPreferredH(titleImage.getHeight());" Is it the good way to set height? Because the height changes slightly in android mobiles I have tested, however it looks horribly big in tabs, and I tested it in different simulator, the height differs greatly. How have you set the toolbar height in normal toolbar?

```
Image titleImage = theme.getImage("toolbar_bg.jpg");
containerTitle.getAllStyles().setBgImage(titleImage);
containerTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_HORIZONTAL);
containerTitle.setPreferredH(titleImage.getHeight());

ScaleImageButton ruslanLogo = new ScaleImageButton();

toolbar.setTitleComponent(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(containerTitle,
        FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ruslanLogo)));
```

4)How can I set the width of icon?

```
Image emergencyImage = theme.getImage("emergency.png");
Button emergencyButton = getButton(emergencyImage);
```

if I just do this, some devices the icon is too big.If I scale it eg: emergencyImage.scaledWidth(screenwidth/8) , the image quality is bad.If I set preferredW like emergencyButton.setPreferredW(100), the img width varies vastly in different devices. PS the images in the theme are saved as multiImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the preferred width/height is problematic as it implies the inverse dimension and might have quite a few implications. I noticed you used:

```
Image ruslanLogoImage = theme.getImage("ruslanLogo.png").scaledWidth(toolbar.getPreferredH() - 180);
```

Which sets the width based on the preferred height instead of the `width/5` or something like that. It also sets the value based on preferred height before the toolbar construction is done so things will behave differently.

Preferred width includes padding which might affect your design. I would suggest creating a center aligned 0 padding/margin UIID in the designer and setting it to all of your components to eliminate padding/margin differences and shorten your code.